# Method to get the location of the maximum number in the queue

Tags: java, arrays, queue, max

I wrote a method to get the maximum number in the queue , but I need to return the location of the maximum number in the queue .
this is the max method I wrote :

```
public int maxValue(int[] array) {
    int maximum = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maximum) {
            maximum = array[i];
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

Comment: Hint : The location of the maximum is 0 at the beginning, and becomes i each time you find a new maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `int maximumIndex` besides:

```
int maximumIndex = 0;
...
        maximumIndex = i;
...
return maximumIndex;
```

Comment: @JreTom Side note: you can start your loop with `int i=1` instead of `int i=0`.